# R - RStudio hangs/crashes creating double-precision large numeric vector

Tags: r, floating-point, rstudio, significant-digits

I have a numeric vector of 500 values that I'm trying to load into R to do some graphical calculations and displays, and every time I try my client hangs/crashes (RStudio). The system doesn't immediately crash, but hangs indefinitely with a plus sign "+" in the console following the closing parenthesis of my assign statement, like this:

```
..., 108.00968, 27.14654, 80.60948)
+
```

Normally you can recover from this kind of "waiting for more info" state by hitting the escape key, which drops the console back into input mode with a cursor. However, with in this situation it produces a crash (Windows "X program has stopped working" message). No error messages are displayed in the R console. I checked to make sure I'm closing the final parentheses and am actually copy-pasting the first part of the code between lines that work and don't work so they should be syntactically identical, which hopefully eliminates any potential for this to be caused by typo errors (exact code at end of post). This leads me to believe that the behavior I'm seeing is caused by the size/quantity/type of the numbers.

From what I understand and can find online relating to vector sizes there isn't a "max size" in R, but if I try to even do something as simple as create the vector then I get a crash. I can load a limited number of them (like 160), but 500 is apparently too many.

Some example values I'm trying to load:

```
outvals <- c(0.794933476174234, 3.5128642241260697, 10.28598660205886, 31.027889828462865)
```

These numbers are double-precision values outputted from another program in Java and so they have a large number of digits after the decimal and sometimes they output with E notation, which I'm not sure if R accepts, so at first I thought this could be a potential cause, even though I hadn't seen any E's in my quick scan of the data. My first attempt to solve this was to convert my output to have only 5 digits after the decimal, which *still* caused the same hang/crash behavior when I had 500 elements. Example values:

```
outvals <- c(.60791, 1.41808, 2.67098, 64.52197, 75.09749, 140.1268, 187.34739, 52.6446)
```

Eventually, I got this to successfully load with no hanging/crashing when I reduced the post-decimal significant digits to 2 (or when I reduced the number of elements in the vector) but I'm losing a great deal of precision and I don't think splitting my vector into 4 or 5 parts is an acceptable solution. Thankfully, the loss of precision is not an absolute deal breaker at this point, but I'm wondering what the best way is to use values with a large number of decimal places. I don't think 500 is *that* large of a vector and 5 decimal places isn't *that* many places, so there should be a way to do this. Do I need to read the input from a file instead of directly putting the values in the .R file? Is R just not able to handle large numbers of significant digits? Or is this just an RStudio problem and I need to go into command-line R (assuming this is possible) or use a different client?

Exact lines that I'm running when I get these errors (note, these are looooong):

```
#these two work
outvals <- c(.79, .74, 1.82, 52.2, 8.28, 19.81, 152.19, 27.57, 8.58, 8.94, 253.48, 132.49, 46.95, 258.61, 290.66, 149.3, 130.05, 355.48, 574.56, 382.83, 482.18, 218.08, 335.23, 290.66, 382.83, 498.58, 402.39, 482.18, 193.75, 417.4, 218.08, 402.39, 141.74, 402.39, 402.39, 315.86, 498.58, 290.66, 218.08, 498.58, 417.4, 355.48, 166.87, 218.08, 54.74, 258.61, 376.89, 258.61, 376.89, 166.87, 66.88, 475.09, 218.08, 168.18, 55.84, 382.83, 355.48, 482.18, 218.08, 382.83, 376.89, 245.65, 498.58, 355.48, 253.48, 355.48, 335.23, 290.66, 335.23, 335.23, 308.35, 245.65, 144.95, 253.48, 355.48, 355.48, 376.89, 498.58, 128.06, 166.87, 482.18, 498.58, 335.23, 355.48, 308.35, 376.89, 382.83, 355.48, 258.61, 258.61, 218.08, 258.61, 218.08, 144.95, 258.61, 206.9, 53.3, 218.08, 355.48, 42.07, 258.61, 106.65, 193.75, 376.89, 376.89, 258.61, 417.4, 355.48, 56.6, 258.61, 498.58, 100.65, 193.75, 131.62, 138.27, 24.88, 131.62, 315.86, 148.55, 417.4, 382.83, 77.4, 206.9, 218.08, 308.35, 112.75, 355.48, 376.89, 417.4, 475.09, 66.88, 132.49, 482.18, 126.63, 144.95, 475.09, 382.83, 218.08, 308.35, 138.27, 303.44, 245.65, 355.48, 355.48, 355.48, 179.4, 315.86, 350.74, 498.58, 482.18, 417.4, 482.18, 141.74, 417.4, 417.4, 482.18, 206.9, 382.83, 498.58, 141.74, 482.18, 382.83, 290.66, 417.4, 498.58, 18.72, 290.66, 222.31, 475.09, 193.76, 144.95, 209.94, 132.49, 193.75, 141.74, 382.83, 144.95, 179.4, 141.74, 112.75, 185.55, 212.05, 498.58, 138.27, 290.66, 218.08, 482.18, 355.48, 482.18, 303.44, 482.18, 40.71, 144.95, 417.4, 350.74, 258.61, 218.08, 290.66, 140.8, 355.48, 382.83, 382.83, 303.44, 417.4, 149.3, 335.23, 131.62, 482.18, 335.23, 117.68, 475.09, 236.95, 95.89, 94.67, 193.75, 355.48, 355.48, 355.48, 209.94, 308.35, 100.65, 417.4, 382.83, 222.31, 253.48, 193.75, 482.18, 132.49, 112.75, 315.86, 498.58, 417.4, 290.66, 209.94, 376.89, 315.86, 402.39, 335.23, 253.48, 130.05, 130.05, 308.35, 315.86, 149.3, 417.4, 141.74, 475.09, 402.39, 149.3, 482.18, 152.19, 498.58, 117.68, 417.4, 209.94, 355.48, 193.76, 498.58, 258.61, 236.95, 308.35, 382.83, 498.58, 402.39, 417.4, 382.83, 209.94, 290.66, 104.92, 149.3, 209.94, 382.83, 102.12, 417.4, 218.08, 417.4, 149.3, 382.83, 185.55, 258.61, 218.08, 382.83, 166.87, 290.66, 382.83, 417.4, 355.48, 350.74, 308.35, 123.19, 308.35, 417.4, 335.23, 482.18, 258.61, 258.61, 193.75, 402.39, 206.9, 290.66, 402.39, 475.09, 132.49, 303.44, 382.83, 100.65, 382.83, 355.48, 56.95, 355.48, 482.18, 193.76, 218.08, 218.08, 290.66, 402.39, 131.62, 290.66, 141.74, 382.83, 149.3, 193.75, 74.45, 258.61, 209.94, 355.48, 179.4, 417.4, 315.86, 168.18, 218.08, 144.95, 382.83, 258.61, 308.35, 482.18, 56.6, 482.18, 245.65, 36.24, 209.94, 253.48, 206.9, 209.94, 382.83, 290.66, 303.44, 417.4, 482.18, 417.4, 193.76, 140.8, 179.4, 308.35, 498.58, 402.39, 482.18, 236.95, 290.66, 179.4, 47.97, 355.48, 382.83, 141.74, 355.48, 402.39, 355.48, 417.4, 350.74, 498.58, 218.08, 376.89, 218.08, 258.61, 141.74, 141.74, 417.4, 54.43, 212.05, 382.83, 206.9, 290.66, 417.4, 498.58, 350.74, 475.09, 152.19, 218.08, 417.4, 350.74, 222.31, 107.62, 236.95, 475.09, 382.83, 335.23, 121.63, 482.18, 245.65, 97, 355.48, 482.18, 144.95, 355.48, 193.75, 498.58, 107.62, 149.3, 402.39, 212.05, 350.74, 193.75, 218.08, 498.58, 355.48, 382.83, 382.83, 475.09, 158.05, 417.4, 417.4, 482.18, 417.4, 308.35, 308.35, 475.09, 417.4, 498.58, 315.86, 138.49, 258.61, 417.4, 245.65, 290.66, 88.81, 106.65, 350.74, 355.48, 54.43, 417.4, 475.09, 402.39, 290.66, 417.4, 132.49, 315.86, 498.58, 258.61, 193.75, 104.92, 382.83, 355.48, 253.48, 498.58, 206.9, 144.95, 475.09, 132.49, 335.23, 335.23, 144.95, 123.61, 308.35, 258.61, 355.48, 245.65, 148.55, 402.39, 290.66, 475.09, 83.26, 355.48, 315.86, 482.18, 402.39, 498.58, 355.48, 382.83, 245.65, 498.58, 475.09, 382.83, 132.49, 149.3, 88.81, 97, 179.4, 253.48, 290.66, 402.39, 131.62, 258.61, 350.74, 303.44, 290.66, 417.4, 144.95, 258.61, 218.08, 417.4)
#outvals2 <- c(0.794933476174234, 3.5128642241260697, 10.28598660205886, 1.2600302126171676, 31.027889828462865, 23.15000712709929, 58.729154521223705, 215.20432675441222, 579.464993879136, 63.513880162215074, 28.959698405287885, 209.63516732070275, 30.04782600303195, 227.43869446888698, 248.36596491018696, 104.73409955976528, 198.6342145598211, 209.63516732070275, 57.94793264204458, 19.270899100358694, 75.48241317584373, 57.24657127591748, 215.20432675441222, 63.513880162215074, 129.49784893861533, 129.49784893861533, 84.17040085625115, 76.70797460822122, 91.82036558044324, 129.49784893861533, 35.07397649759432, 236.36650346927524, 215.20432675441222, 209.63516732070275, 66.73838207163915, 91.82036558044324, 209.63516732070275, 319.3443889268936, 272.8438185545791, 198.6342145598211, 76.70797460822122, 227.43869446888698, 319.3443889268936, 50.68629607409348, 69.9802325820079, 292.3597033095136, 352.4353730767199, 154.26895025584872, 90.79642288841237, 209.63516732070275, 579.464993879136, 70.90044394183283, 67.67827698750271, 80.3650258687956, 35.2778346576937, 63.477432984723634, 129.49784893861533, 226.64891288273682, 56.78530609937027, 76.70797460822122, 66.06221851141238, 130.5794634173596, 482.3668721692566, 158.1826251421317, 319.3443889268936, 220.30424892054754, 72.01360115410559, 158.1826251421317, 47.664694805008445, 55.7433846988939, 226.64891288273682, 307.0681488517892, 72.01360115410559, 198.6342145598211, 248.36596491018696, 121.89181544023398, 495.3154941026644, 158.1826251421317, 227.43869446888698, 84.17040085625115, 248.36596491018696, 579.4649938791359, 209.63516732070275, 76.70797460822122, 130.5794634173596, 198.6342145598211, 190.64187081796223, 227.43869446888698, 236.36650346927524, 209.63516732070275, 126.66295614580373, 209.63516732070275, 292.3597033095136, 154.26895025584872, 209.63516732070275, 198.6342145598211, 307.0681488517892, 126.66295614580373, 226.64891288273682, 122.02855436204793, 227.43869446888698, 209.63516732070275, 482.3668721692566, 129.49784893861533, 111.00370932068954, 319.3443889268936, 41.037381109315845, 190.64187081796223, 272.8438185545791, 80.3650258687956, 40.936887639122496, 100.09035288521471, 154.26895025584872, 65.31566090651495, 75.48241317584373, 579.4649938791359, 168.39771099808507, 220.30424892054754, 190.64187081796223, 215.20432675441222, 495.3154941026644, 70.90044394183283, 90.79642288841237, 126.66295614580373, 168.39771099808507, 53.82899843425185, 236.36650346927524, 292.3597033095136, 319.3443889268936, 122.02855436204793, 31.210156250385943, 307.0681488517892, 579.4649938791359, 227.43869446888698, 579.4649938791359, 154.26895025584872, 111.00370932068954, 352.4353730767199, 319.3443889268936, 495.3154941026644, 352.4353730767199, 85.56443246095841, 69.9802325820079, 85.56443246095841, 65.31566090651495, 129.43115354241297, 154.26895025584872, 67.67827698750271, 198.6342145598211, 85.56443246095841, 226.64891288273682, 104.73409955976528, 236.36650346927524, 50.65492008278703, 272.8438185545791, 130.5794634173596, 38.54396326738687, 29.812250453066387, 220.30424892054754, 111.00370932068954)

#These ones don't
#outvals3 <- c(.60791, .44997, .79496, .90661, 1.41808, 2.67098, 3.94923, 75.09749, 75.09749, 40.59529, 64.52197, 64.52197, 75.09749, 140.1268, 187.34739, 110.56475, 179.12011, 111.78596, 131.68193, 146.97732, 52.6446, 28.93388, 165.7578, 140.1268, 186.67669, 131.68193, 185.64969, 224.62772, 137.45174, 224.62772, 130.69029, 117.98915, 56.91589, 95.70941, 118.18941, 229.36556, 117.98915, 187.34739, 175.21006, 187.34739, 224.62772, 175.21006, 75.09749, 172.9537, 185.64969, 165.7578, 186.67669, 146.34013, 115.12518, 95.70941, 66.03041, 172.9537, 235.59637, 157.02953, 94.07931, 143.56451, 167.97113, 143.30155, 146.34013, 108.00968, 224.62772, 374.0517, 255.67384, 88.4808, 195.44411, 191.25343, 185.64969, 130.69029, 374.0517, 167.97113, 179.12011, 429.30365, 106.67926, 151.07274, 117.98915, 143.56451, 111.78596, 382.77066, 130.69029, 50.83587, 172.9537, 143.30155, 286.65833, 172.9537, 256.44452, 198.71409, 255.67384, 235.59637, 179.12011, 167.97113, 187.34739, 140.1268, 40.59529, 58.9625, 374.0517, 224.62772, 255.67384, 80.60948, 166.80923, 166.80923, 118.88632, 93.83426, 68.8146, 256.44452, 255.67384, 118.88632, 67.68099, 560.65039, 453.68289, 382.77066, 198.71409, 154.11321, 185.51567, 327.81446, 327.81446, 374.0517, 224.62772, 117.98915, 453.68289, 140.1268, 327.81446, 198.71409, 185.64969, 110.56475, 453.68289, 151.07274, 382.77066, 93.83426, 187.34739, 167.97113, 51.39773, 453.68289, 560.65039, 42.86032, 327.81446, 186.67669, 255.67384, 187.34739, 185.64969, 382.77066, 166.80923, 185.64969, 286.65833, 187.34739, 560.65039, 120.29011, 165.7578, 274.4352, 104.55168, 185.51567, 274.4352, 327.81446, 185.64969, 89.11919, 195.44411, 198.71409, 191.25343, 69.95528, 195.44411, 256.44452, 185.64969, 140.1268, 110.56475, 382.77066, 327.81446, 198.71409, 117.98915, 93.83426, 70.55312, 157.02953, 198.71409, 186.67669, 98.36025, 198.71409, 327.81446, 224.62772, 115.12518, 382.77066, 186.67669, 164.3344, 118.88632, 224.62772, 30.92701, 185.51567, 327.81446, 186.67669, 151.07274, 374.0517, 198.71409, 54.92275, 255.67384, 151.07274, 185.51567, 185.51567, 374.0517, 224.62772, 106.67926, 255.67384, 186.67669, 185.64969, 453.68289, 406.21377, 382.77066, 256.44452, 151.07274, 110.56475, 69.72398, 120.29011, 198.71409, 382.77066, 560.65039, 143.56451, 274.4352, 50.05464, 40.59529, 104.55168, 164.3344, 172.9537, 172.9537, 143.56451, 374.0517, 198.71409, 67.68099, 94.07931, 255.67384, 453.68289, 82.03707, 198.71409, 50.05464, 327.81446, 166.80923, 198.71409, 130.69029, 106.67926, 382.77066, 167.97113, 120.29011, 157.02953, 165.99886, 453.68289, 382.77066, 224.62772, 374.0517, 88.4808, 327.81446, 327.81446, 72.37382, 88.4808, 406.21377, 77.09608, 224.62772, 374.0517, 179.12011, 327.81446, 120.29011, 143.56451, 256.44452, 195.44411, 88.01403, 186.67669, 187.34739, 143.30155, 406.21377, 560.65039, 256.44452, 77.09608, 115.12518, 164.3344, 54.06305, 185.64969, 166.80923, 235.59637, 172.9537, 198.71409, 165.7578, 191.25343, 165.7578, 164.3344, 255.67384, 77.09608, 72.95142, 382.77066, 67.16891, 172.9537, 64.52197, 560.65039, 327.81446, 77.38478, 429.30365, 198.71409, 120.29011, 560.65039, 186.67669, 255.67384, 560.65039, 179.12011, 88.4808, 255.67384, 560.65039, 286.65833, 165.99886, 157.02953, 256.44452, 274.4352, 286.65833, 47.97041, 97.24981, 151.07274, 157.02953, 80.60948, 69.72398, 255.67384, 58.9625, 165.99886, 75.19083, 198.71409, 224.62772, 453.68289, 453.68289, 154.11321, 560.65039, 93.83426, 117.98915, 286.65833, 185.64969, 165.99886, 54.06305, 429.30365, 122.23162, 94.07931, 187.34739, 429.30365, 382.77066, 140.1268, 179.12011, 120.29011, 235.59637, 374.0517, 255.67384, 164.3344, 195.44411, 327.81446, 256.44452, 185.51567, 82.03707, 185.51567, 560.65039, 191.25343, 166.80923, 560.65039, 186.67669, 95.95364, 120.29011, 191.25343, 327.81446, 185.51567, 191.25343, 224.62772, 51.39773, 151.07274, 172.9537, 255.67384, 406.21377, 406.21377, 235.59637, 166.80923, 235.59637, 187.34739, 111.78596, 93.83426, 256.44452, 186.67669, 286.65833, 235.59637, 274.4352, 172.9537, 143.56451, 154.11321, 255.67384, 255.67384, 166.80923, 255.67384, 187.34739, 165.99886, 88.4808, 453.68289, 198.71409, 235.59637, 286.65833, 560.65039, 69.95528, 191.25343, 110.56475, 59.89974, 327.81446, 187.34739, 185.64969, 172.9537, 560.65039, 235.59637, 195.44411, 286.65833, 256.44452, 224.62772, 274.4352, 429.30365, 122.23162, 185.64969, 143.30155, 96.39451, 185.51567, 195.44411, 274.4352, 274.4352, 286.65833, 157.02953, 374.0517, 374.0517, 167.97113, 256.44452, 57.85034, 82.03707, 286.65833, 186.67669, 172.9537, 255.67384, 143.56451, 75.19083, 185.51567, 453.68289, 151.07274, 167.97113, 143.30155, 115.12518, 256.44452, 286.65833, 429.30365, 256.44452, 255.67384, 130.69029, 255.67384, 374.0517, 256.44452, 79.08417, 111.78596, 382.77066, 185.51567, 111.78596, 80.60948, 406.21377, 165.7578, 255.67384, 96.39451, 7.34742, 382.77066, 191.25343, 166.80923, 98.36025, 167.97113, 429.30365, 179.12011, 224.62772, 69.15261, 186.67669, 172.9537, 43.36202, 57.0059, 88.01403, 68.8146, 382.77066, 140.1268, 286.65833, 88.01403, 198.71409, 186.67669, 115.12518, 274.4352, 165.99886, 453.68289, 166.80923, 164.3344, 191.25343, 429.30365, 172.9537, 224.62772, 143.56451, 88.01403, 104.55168, 151.07274, 453.68289, 115.12518, 130.69029, 198.71409, 255.67384, 166.80923, 374.0517, 255.67384, 108.00968, 27.14654, 80.60948)
#outvals4 <- c(0.794933476174234, 3.5128642241260697, 10.28598660205886, 1.2600302126171676, 31.027889828462865, 23.15000712709929, 58.729154521223705, 215.20432675441222, 579.464993879136, 63.513880162215074, 28.959698405287885, 209.63516732070275, 30.04782600303195, 227.43869446888698, 248.36596491018696, 104.73409955976528, 198.6342145598211, 209.63516732070275, 57.94793264204458, 19.270899100358694, 75.48241317584373, 57.24657127591748, 215.20432675441222, 63.513880162215074, 129.49784893861533, 129.49784893861533, 84.17040085625115, 76.70797460822122, 91.82036558044324, 129.49784893861533, 35.07397649759432, 236.36650346927524, 215.20432675441222, 209.63516732070275, 66.73838207163915, 91.82036558044324, 209.63516732070275, 319.3443889268936, 272.8438185545791, 198.6342145598211, 76.70797460822122, 227.43869446888698, 319.3443889268936, 50.68629607409348, 69.9802325820079, 292.3597033095136, 352.4353730767199, 154.26895025584872, 90.79642288841237, 209.63516732070275, 579.464993879136, 70.90044394183283, 67.67827698750271, 80.3650258687956, 35.2778346576937, 63.477432984723634, 129.49784893861533, 226.64891288273682, 56.78530609937027, 76.70797460822122, 66.06221851141238, 130.5794634173596, 482.3668721692566, 158.1826251421317, 319.3443889268936, 220.30424892054754, 72.01360115410559, 158.1826251421317, 47.664694805008445, 55.7433846988939, 226.64891288273682, 307.0681488517892, 72.01360115410559, 198.6342145598211, 248.36596491018696, 121.89181544023398, 495.3154941026644, 158.1826251421317, 227.43869446888698, 84.17040085625115, 248.36596491018696, 579.4649938791359, 209.63516732070275, 76.70797460822122, 130.5794634173596, 198.6342145598211, 190.64187081796223, 227.43869446888698, 236.36650346927524, 209.63516732070275, 126.66295614580373, 209.63516732070275, 292.3597033095136, 154.26895025584872, 209.63516732070275, 198.6342145598211, 307.0681488517892, 126.66295614580373, 226.64891288273682, 122.02855436204793, 227.43869446888698, 209.63516732070275, 482.3668721692566, 129.49784893861533, 111.00370932068954, 319.3443889268936, 41.037381109315845, 190.64187081796223, 272.8438185545791, 80.3650258687956, 40.936887639122496, 100.09035288521471, 154.26895025584872, 65.31566090651495, 75.48241317584373, 579.4649938791359, 168.39771099808507, 220.30424892054754, 190.64187081796223, 215.20432675441222, 495.3154941026644, 70.90044394183283, 90.79642288841237, 126.66295614580373, 168.39771099808507, 53.82899843425185, 236.36650346927524, 292.3597033095136, 319.3443889268936, 122.02855436204793, 31.210156250385943, 307.0681488517892, 579.4649938791359, 227.43869446888698, 579.4649938791359, 154.26895025584872, 111.00370932068954, 352.4353730767199, 319.3443889268936, 495.3154941026644, 352.4353730767199, 85.56443246095841, 69.9802325820079, 85.56443246095841, 65.31566090651495, 129.43115354241297, 154.26895025584872, 67.67827698750271, 198.6342145598211, 85.56443246095841, 226.64891288273682, 104.73409955976528, 236.36650346927524, 50.65492008278703, 272.8438185545791, 130.5794634173596, 38.54396326738687, 29.812250453066387, 220.30424892054754, 111.00370932068954)
#outvals5 <- c(0.794933476174234, 3.5128642241260697, 10.28598660205886, 1.2600302126171676, 31.027889828462865, 23.15000712709929, 58.729154521223705, 215.20432675441222, 579.464993879136, 63.513880162215074, 28.959698405287885, 209.63516732070275, 30.04782600303195, 227.43869446888698, 248.36596491018696, 104.73409955976528, 198.6342145598211, 209.63516732070275, 57.94793264204458, 19.270899100358694, 75.48241317584373, 57.24657127591748, 215.20432675441222, 63.513880162215074, 129.49784893861533, 129.49784893861533, 84.17040085625115, 76.70797460822122, 91.82036558044324, 129.49784893861533, 35.07397649759432, 236.36650346927524, 215.20432675441222, 209.63516732070275, 66.73838207163915, 91.82036558044324, 209.63516732070275, 319.3443889268936, 272.8438185545791, 198.6342145598211, 76.70797460822122, 227.43869446888698, 319.3443889268936, 50.68629607409348, 69.9802325820079, 292.3597033095136, 352.4353730767199, 154.26895025584872, 90.79642288841237, 209.63516732070275, 579.464993879136, 70.90044394183283, 67.67827698750271, 80.3650258687956, 35.2778346576937, 63.477432984723634, 129.49784893861533, 226.64891288273682, 56.78530609937027, 76.70797460822122, 66.06221851141238, 130.5794634173596, 482.3668721692566, 158.1826251421317, 319.3443889268936, 220.30424892054754, 72.01360115410559, 158.1826251421317, 47.664694805008445, 55.7433846988939, 226.64891288273682, 307.0681488517892, 72.01360115410559, 198.6342145598211, 248.36596491018696, 121.89181544023398, 495.3154941026644, 158.1826251421317, 227.43869446888698, 84.17040085625115, 248.36596491018696, 579.4649938791359, 209.63516732070275, 76.70797460822122, 130.5794634173596, 198.6342145598211, 190.64187081796223, 227.43869446888698, 236.36650346927524, 209.63516732070275, 126.66295614580373, 209.63516732070275, 292.3597033095136, 154.26895025584872, 209.63516732070275, 198.6342145598211, 307.0681488517892, 126.66295614580373, 226.64891288273682, 122.02855436204793, 227.43869446888698, 209.63516732070275, 482.3668721692566, 129.49784893861533, 111.00370932068954, 319.3443889268936, 41.037381109315845, 190.64187081796223, 272.8438185545791, 80.3650258687956, 40.936887639122496, 100.09035288521471, 154.26895025584872, 65.31566090651495, 75.48241317584373, 579.4649938791359, 168.39771099808507, 220.30424892054754, 190.64187081796223, 215.20432675441222, 495.3154941026644, 70.90044394183283, 90.79642288841237, 126.66295614580373, 168.39771099808507, 53.82899843425185, 236.36650346927524, 292.3597033095136, 319.3443889268936, 122.02855436204793, 31.210156250385943, 307.0681488517892, 579.4649938791359, 227.43869446888698, 579.4649938791359, 154.26895025584872, 111.00370932068954, 352.4353730767199, 319.3443889268936, 495.3154941026644, 352.4353730767199, 85.56443246095841, 69.9802325820079, 85.56443246095841, 65.31566090651495, 129.43115354241297, 154.26895025584872, 67.67827698750271, 198.6342145598211, 85.56443246095841, 226.64891288273682, 104.73409955976528, 236.36650346927524, 50.65492008278703, 272.8438185545791, 130.5794634173596, 38.54396326738687, 29.812250453066387, 220.30424892054754, 111.00370932068954, 579.4649938791359, 307.0681488517892, 121.89181544023398, 129.43115354241297, 236.36650346927524, 111.00370932068954, 292.3597033095136, 482.3668721692566, 70.90044394183283, 84.17040085625115, 209.63516732070275, 107.93708121135573, 220.30424892054754, 215.20432675441222, 154.26895025584872, 209.63516732070275, 220.30424892054754, 495.3154941026644, 111.00370932068954, 52.13578764785762, 158.1826251421317, 236.36650346927524, 44.27137951523684, 55.7433846988939, 129.49784893861533, 198.6342145598211, 236.36650346927524, 40.936887639122496, 130.5794634173596, 579.4649938791359, 102.36716674204195, 226.64891288273682, 209.63516732070275, 579.4649938791359, 272.8438185545791, 129.49784893861533, 24.176331515541015, 272.8438185545791, 21.65521216355967, 126.66295614580373, 80.3650258687956, 227.43869446888698, 190.64187081796223, 198.6342145598211, 226.64891288273682, 102.36716674204195, 319.3443889268936, 121.89181544023398, 53.82899843425185, 495.3154941026644, 227.43869446888698, 129.49784893861533, 69.9802325820079, 307.0681488517892, 198.6342145598211, 579.4649938791359, 319.3443889268936, 307.0681488517892, 24.176331515541015, 53.82899843425185, 248.36596491018696, 20.430141561245247, 307.0681488517892, 90.79642288841237, 579.4649938791359, 236.36650346927524, 198.6342145598211, 47.664694805008445, 126.66295614580373, 55.7433846988939, 168.39771099808507, 190.64187081796223, 129.43115354241297, 482.3668721692566, 307.0681488517892, 91.82036558044324, 75.48241317584373, 319.3443889268936, 91.82036558044324, 168.39771099808507, 65.31566090651495, 272.8438185545791, 154.26895025584872, 248.36596491018696, 45.34858148728487, 190.64187081796223, 35.25533585442108, 319.3443889268936, 168.39771099808507, 209.63516732070275, 495.3154941026644, 190.64187081796223, 66.06221851141238, 23.15000712709929, 129.49784893861533, 129.43115354241297, 579.4649938791359, 41.037381109315845, 227.43869446888698, 84.17040085625115, 63.477432984723634, 220.30424892054754, 292.3597033095136, 154.26895025584872, 70.90044394183283, 352.4353730767199, 579.4649938791359, 215.20432675441222, 76.70797460822122, 53.82899843425185, 84.17040085625115, 50.68629607409348, 495.3154941026644, 100.09035288521471, 65.31566090651495, 90.79642288841237, 75.48241317584373, 226.64891288273682, 190.64187081796223, 76.70797460822122, 154.26895025584872, 111.00370932068954, 45.34858148728487, 41.77956139467641, 352.4353730767199, 352.4353730767199, 319.3443889268936, 579.4649938791359, 220.30424892054754, 307.0681488517892, 74.31084452009584, 154.26895025584872, 236.36650346927524, 352.4353730767199, 292.3597033095136, 482.3668721692566, 130.5794634173596, 482.3668721692566, 226.64891288273682, 307.0681488517892, 319.3443889268936, 220.30424892054754, 272.8438185545791, 38.54396326738687, 116.14008922774948, 482.3668721692566, 482.3668721692566, 20.52255662588617, 154.26895025584872, 482.3668721692566, 80.3650258687956, 107.93708121135573, 579.4649938791359, 352.4353730767199, 236.36650346927524, 130.5794634173596, 579.4649938791359, 482.3668721692566, 248.36596491018696, 248.36596491018696, 70.90044394183283, 63.477432984723634, 495.3154941026644, 65.31566090651495, 482.3668721692566, 74.31084452009584, 236.36650346927524, 56.78530609937027, 129.49784893861533, 352.4353730767199, 129.43115354241297, 154.26895025584872, 91.82036558044324, 227.43869446888698, 227.43869446888698, 220.30424892054754, 220.30424892054754, 226.64891288273682, 47.29935033194551, 52.13578764785762, 292.3597033095136, 352.4353730767199, 319.3443889268936, 579.4649938791359, 38.54396326738687, 90.79642288841237, 352.4353730767199, 319.3443889268936, 482.3668721692566, 352.4353730767199, 198.6342145598211, 352.4353730767199, 63.513880162215074, 50.65492008278703, 319.3443889268936, 248.36596491018696, 215.20432675441222, 76.70797460822122, 292.3597033095136, 482.3668721692566, 56.78530609937027, 67.67827698750271, 90.79642288841237, 495.3154941026644, 248.36596491018696, 129.49784893861533, 80.3650258687956, 130.5794634173596, 190.64187081796223, 66.06221851141238, 236.36650346927524, 104.73409955976528, 319.3443889268936, 482.3668721692566, 272.8438185545791, 220.30424892054754, 292.3597033095136, 130.5794634173596, 198.6342145598211, 272.8438185545791, 57.24657127591748, 90.79642288841237, 272.8438185545791, 352.4353730767199, 168.39771099808507, 248.36596491018696, 209.63516732070275, 66.73838207163915, 129.43115354241297, 129.49784893861533, 272.8438185545791, 579.4649938791359, 100.09035288521471, 220.30424892054754, 319.3443889268936, 13.94683840755955, 272.8438185545791, 154.26895025584872, 104.73409955976528, 130.5794634173596, 307.0681488517892, 107.93708121135573, 36.61031136872027, 36.61031136872027, 84.17040085625115, 31.210156250385943, 72.01360115410559, 126.66295614580373, 190.64187081796223, 90.79642288841237, 209.63516732070275, 158.1826251421317, 236.36650346927524, 579.4649938791359, 292.3597033095136, 36.825079570584506, 116.14008922774948, 168.39771099808507, 129.49784893861533, 482.3668721692566, 126.66295614580373, 168.39771099808507, 272.8438185545791, 107.93708121135573, 158.1826251421317, 168.39771099808507, 198.6342145598211, 220.30424892054754, 70.90044394183283, 579.4649938791359, 57.94793264204458, 56.78530609937027, 319.3443889268936, 319.3443889268936, 292.3597033095136, 154.26895025584872, 190.64187081796223, 209.63516732070275, 579.4649938791359, 65.31566090651495, 70.90044394183283, 198.6342145598211, 319.3443889268936, 129.49784893861533, 158.1826251421317, 220.30424892054754, 248.36596491018696, 227.43869446888698, 57.24657127591748, 307.0681488517892, 85.56443246095841, 36.61031136872027, 158.1826251421317, 130.5794634173596, 129.49784893861533, 154.26895025584872, 198.6342145598211, 55.7433846988939, 100.09035288521471, 227.43869446888698, 220.30424892054754, 579.4649938791359, 44.27137951523684, 90.79642288841237, 129.43115354241297, 154.26895025584872, 226.64891288273682, 69.19008543950986, 130.5794634173596, 307.0681488517892, 209.63516732070275, 272.8438185545791, 215.20432675441222, 272.8438185545791, 129.43115354241297, 107.93708121135573, 236.36650346927524, 319.3443889268936, 272.8438185545791, 579.4649938791359, 126.66295614580373, 70.90044394183283, 63.477432984723634, 227.43869446888698, 352.4353730767199, 236.36650346927524, 292.3597033095136, 495.3154941026644, 198.6342145598211, 17.660120057543903, 158.1826251421317, 190.64187081796223, 209.63516732070275, 45.80777034221213, 307.0681488517892, 198.6342145598211, 32.76209974792738, 84.17040085625115, 58.729154521223705, 482.3668721692566)
```

Also, version info is:

```
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          1.2                         
year           2014                        
month          10                          
day            31                          
svn rev        66913                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
nickname       Pumpkin Helmet
```